# ping problems, one can ping other, but other can't in reverse way

Tags: networking, ping

I have two laptops connected through Wireless LAN Ad hoc network.

Laptop A: IP: 192.168.1.119, Subnet: 255.255.255.0, Windows 7 Enterprise X64, manually given IP to WLAN NIC, member of Domain, Firewall - OFF (Off for all, public, private, domain profiles).

Laptop B: IP: 192.168.1.111, Subnet: 255.255.255.0, Windows 7 Home Basic X64, manually given IP to WLAN NIC, NOT member of Domain (We can say member of workgroup "WORKGROUP"), Firewall - OFF (Off for all, public, private, domain profiles).

Laptop A can ping to laptop B. But when I try to ping laptop A from laptop B, it shows me Timeout.

Please help me. Firewall is off on both.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified ALL firewalls are off on both machines? Typically this is the main issue for me, personally, regarding ping. Have you checked Windows Firewall and any anti-virus software you've got installed?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check tcpdump or wireshark on laptop B on interface where packets should go out. Maybe this is a routing issue and packets are stacked somewhere without being send from laptop B.

If this is not the case then try to do the same on laptop A to see if ICMP packets are reaching laptop A. In this case you will also see if ICMP Request is being send by laptop A.